# Process single data set with different JSON schema rows using Pyspark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am using PySpark and I need to process the log files that are appended into a single data frame. Most of the columns are look normal, but one of the columns has JSON string in {}. Basically, each row is an individual event and for JSON string I can apply individual Schema. But I don't know what is the best way to process data here.

Example:
[image]

This table later will help to aggregate the events in the way I need.

I tried to use function `withColumn` and use `from_json`. It worked successfully for a single column:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions  as F

df = (df
      .withColumn("nested_json",
                  F.when(F.col("event_name") == "EventStart",F.from_json("json_string","Name String, Version Int, Id Int")))
```

It did for my 1st row what I want when I will query `nested_json`. But it is applied schema on the whole column, and I would like to process each row depends on the `event_name`

I was naive and try to do this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions  as F

df = (df
      .withColumn("nested_json",
                  F.when(F.col("event_name") == "EventStart",F.from_json("json_string","Name String, Version Int, Id Int"))
                  F.when(F.col("event_name") == "Action1",F.from_json("json_string","Name String, Version Int, UserName String, PosX int, PosY int"))
)
```

And this is failed to run with `when() can only be applied on a Column previously generated by when() function`

I assumed, my 1st `withColumn` applied schema for the whole column.

What other options do I have to apply JSON schema based on `event_name` value and flattened values?

Comment: how about using the whole schema like `"Name string, Version int, Id int, UserName string, PosX int . . ."` for all rows without `when` function?

Comment: This option actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

What if you chain your `when` statements?
For example,

```
df.withColumn("nested_json", F.when(F.col("event_name") =="EventStart",F.from_json(...)).when(F.col("event_name") == "Action1", F. from_json(...)))
```

Comment: This is exactly when I get an error `when() can only be applied on a Column previously generated by when() function`